# Cannot insert a backquote in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This is something crazy : I can't insert a backquote in a VueJS (.vue) file with Eclipse!

I open it with the HTML editor of Eclipse and when I put a backquote, it is underlined with a green line and pressing any key afterward removes it.

I am using Eclipse for years with this type of file and its the first time I have this problem.

Trying to put a backquote :

[image: backquote underlined]

And then after pressing any key :

[image]

I'm on Debian with Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22.0)

---

**EDIT**

In fact this behavior appens not only with *.vue files.

I have the same problem with *.md Markdown files as well.

Comment: The HTML Editor doesn't support .vue files, and neither does the Generic Text Editor. Which one are you using, and how did you get it to open it? Were there any messages in the Error Log when you typed the backquotes?

Comment: I just added it in file associations with *.vue and selected HTML editor. Thus I have syntax highlighting for my SFC components for HTML AND for Javascript.

Comment: Do you have a moment to talk about our lord and savior https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ ? You are welcome asking the question here, but you might consider also opening a bug report.

Comment: @kutschkem I was about to do it but I finally found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally found the problem. It is not related to Eclipse.

In the keyboard layout in my OS I had this layout :

**French (deprecated)**

Don't know why I had this random layout though changing it to the correct keyboard layout solved the problem.